# Extracting elevation profile from CSV containing XYZ data

Tags: qgis, xyz, profile

I am new to GIS software.

I have XYZ data in a text file (delimited text). The data is XY in 1m spacing, approx. 12km x 900m of data.

I want to find the elevation profile from a XY path.

In QGIS, i have managed to remove bulk of the unnecessary points to help reduce the time required for interpolation.

I tried using the profile tool to use an existing layer (a line I made), but the program stops responding instead of showing some process bar.

Do I need to do some TIN interpolation before trying to profile tool it again?

Comment: Convert your XYZ to a faster format, I suggest either Erdas Imagine (driver HFA, extension .img) or GeoTIFF. As it is regular spacing you shouldn't need to TIN the data but if direct conversion is problematic have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376582/text-xyz-coordinate-import-gives-data-that-is-not-usable-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150291/creating-tin-from-elevation-points-in-qgis for more in depth instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert you point grid to a raster format using the [Rasterize (vector to raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) tool. Then you can use the Profile Tool plugin to create the profile, as explained here: [QGIS Profile Tool - Terrain Profile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292400/qgis-profile-tool-terrain-profile)